# Why the exactly identical keras model predict different results for the same input data in the same env

Tags: tensorflow, keras, imagenet

I have two models that proven to be identical as following:

```
if len(m_s.layers) != len(m_m.layers):
    print("number of layers are different")
    
for i in range(len(m_s.layers)):
    weight_s = m_s.layers[i].get_weights()
    weight_m = m_m.layers[i].get_weights()

    if len(weight_s) > 0:
        for j in range(len(weight_s)):
            
            if (weight_s[j] == weight_m[j]).all:
                print("layer %d identical" % i)
            else:
                print("!!!!! layer %d not the same" % i)
    else:
        if len(weight_m) == 0:
            print("layer %d identical" % i)
        else:
            print("!!!!! layer %d not the same" % i)
```

and the output shows they are identical. They are slices from the imagenet model.

```
layer 0 identical
layer 1 identical
layer 2 identical
layer 2 identical
layer 2 identical
layer 2 identical
layer 3 identical
layer 4 identical
layer 5 identical
layer 5 identical
layer 5 identical
layer 5 identical
layer 6 identical
layer 7 identical
layer 8 identical
layer 8 identical
layer 8 identical
layer 8 identical
layer 9 identical
layer 10 identical
layer 10 identical
layer 10 identical
layer 10 identical
layer 11 identical
layer 12 identical
layer 13 identical
layer 13 identical
layer 13 identical
layer 13 identical
layer 14 identical
layer 15 identical
layer 16 identical
layer 16 identical
layer 16 identical
layer 16 identical
layer 17 identical
layer 18 identical
layer 18 identical
layer 18 identical
layer 18 identical
layer 19 identical
layer 20 identical
layer 21 identical
layer 21 identical
layer 21 identical
layer 21 identical
layer 22 identical
layer 23 identical
layer 24 identical
layer 24 identical
layer 24 identical
layer 24 identical
layer 25 identical
layer 26 identical
layer 27 identical
layer 27 identical
layer 27 identical
layer 27 identical
layer 28 identical
layer 29 identical
layer 30 identical
layer 30 identical
layer 30 identical
layer 30 identical
layer 31 identical
layer 32 identical
layer 33 identical
layer 33 identical
layer 33 identical
layer 33 identical
layer 34 identical
layer 35 identical
layer 35 identical
layer 35 identical
layer 35 identical
layer 36 identical
layer 37 identical
layer 38 identical
layer 38 identical
layer 38 identical
layer 38 identical
layer 39 identical
layer 40 identical
layer 41 identical
layer 41 identical
layer 41 identical
layer 41 identical
layer 42 identical
layer 43 identical
layer 44 identical
layer 44 identical
layer 44 identical
layer 44 identical
layer 45 identical
layer 46 identical
layer 47 identical
layer 47 identical
layer 47 identical
layer 47 identical
layer 48 identical
layer 49 identical
layer 50 identical
layer 50 identical
layer 50 identical
layer 50 identical
layer 51 identical
```

However, when I used these two model in the same machine and same env to predict the same input data, the outputs were completely different.

```
m_s.predict(data)
```

output

```
array([[[[-2.2014694e+00, -7.4636793e+00, -3.7543521e+00, ...,
           4.2393379e+00,  7.2923303e+00, -7.9203067e+00],
         [-6.8980045e+00, -6.7517347e+00,  5.9752476e-01, ...,
           2.2391853e+00, -2.0161586e+00, -7.5054851e+00],
         [-4.4470978e+00, -4.2420959e+00, -3.9374633e+00, ...,
           5.9843721e+00,  5.4481273e+00, -2.7136576e+00],
         ...,
         [-8.2077494e+00, -5.5874801e+00,  2.2708473e+00, ...,
          -2.5585687e-01,  4.0198727e+00, -4.5880938e+00],
         [-7.5793233e+00, -6.3811040e+00,  3.7389126e+00, ...,
           1.7169635e+00, -3.4249902e-01, -7.1873198e+00],
         [-8.2512989e+00, -4.2883468e+00, -2.7908459e+00, ...,
           3.9796615e+00,  4.7512245e-01, -4.5338011e+00]],
        [[-5.2522459e+00, -5.2272692e+00, -3.7313356e+00, ...,
           1.0820831e+00, -1.9317195e+00, -8.3177958e+00],
         [-5.8229809e+00, -6.8049965e+00, -1.4538713e+00, ...,
           4.0576010e+00, -1.9025326e-02, -8.2517090e+00],
         [-6.1541910e+00, -2.6757658e-01, -5.4412403e+00, ...,
           1.7984511e+00,  2.9016986e+00,  7.6427579e-01],
         ...,
         [-1.1129386e+00,  7.9319181e+00,  7.7404571e-01, ...,
          -1.7145084e+01,  1.5210888e+01,  1.3812095e+01],
         [ 3.5752565e-01,  1.4212518e+00, -6.1826277e-01, ...,
          -3.4348285e+00,  5.1942883e+00,  2.1960042e+00],
         [-6.3907943e+00, -5.3237562e+00, -3.1632636e+00, ...,
           2.1118989e+00, -3.8516359e+00, -6.2463970e+00]],
        [[-7.2064867e+00, -3.6420932e+00, -1.6844990e+00, ...,
           6.4910537e-01, -4.4807429e+00, -7.8619242e+00],
         [-6.4934230e+00, -4.5477719e+00,  9.2149705e-01, ...,
           4.2846882e-01, -7.4903011e-01, -9.8737726e+00],
         [-7.2704558e+00,  9.5214283e-01, -2.0818310e+00, ...,
          -1.6958854e-01,  1.6371614e+00, -2.7756066e+00],
         ...,
         [-7.1980424e+00, -7.2074276e-01,  2.3514495e+00, ...,
          -9.7255888e+00,  2.1547556e-01,  4.3379207e+00],
         [-6.7656651e+00,  6.3100419e+00, -7.8286257e+00, ...,
          -5.1035576e+00, -1.3960669e+00,  2.3991609e+00],
         [-7.0669832e+00, -1.2582588e-01, -5.3176193e+00, ...,
           3.4836166e+00, -2.4024684e+00, -6.0632706e+00]],
        ...,
        [[-7.3400059e+00, -3.1168675e+00, -1.9545169e+00, ...,
           1.0936095e+00, -1.5736668e+00, -9.5641651e+00],
         [-2.9115820e+00, -4.7334772e-01,  2.6805878e-01, ...,
           8.3148491e-01, -1.2751791e+00, -5.5142212e+00],
         [ 1.2365078e+00,  1.0945862e+01, -4.9259267e+00, ...,
           1.9169430e+00,  5.1151342e+00,  4.9710069e+00],
         ...,
         [-2.2321188e+00,  8.8735223e-02, -7.6890874e+00, ...,
          -3.1269640e-01,  7.3404179e+00, -7.2507386e+00],
         [-2.2741010e+00, -6.5992510e-01,  4.0761769e-01, ...,
           1.8645943e+00,  4.0359187e+00, -7.7996893e+00],
         [ 5.5672646e-02, -1.4715804e+00, -1.9753509e+00, ...,
           2.5039923e+00, -1.0506821e-01, -6.5183282e+00]],

        [[-8.3111782e+00, -4.6992331e+00, -3.1351955e+00, ...,
           1.8569698e+00, -1.1717710e+00, -8.5070782e+00],
         [-4.7671299e+00, -2.5072317e+00,  2.9760203e+00, ...,
           2.9142296e+00,  3.2271760e+00, -4.7557964e+00],
         [ 5.5070686e-01,  5.3218126e-02, -2.1629403e+00, ...,
           8.8359457e-01,  3.1481497e+00, -2.1769693e+00],
         ...,
         [-3.7305963e+00, -1.2512873e+00,  2.0231385e+00, ...,
           4.4094267e+00,  3.0268743e+00, -9.6763916e+00],
         [-5.4271636e+00, -4.6796727e+00,  5.7922940e+00, ...,
           3.6725988e+00,  5.2563481e+00, -8.1707211e+00],
         [-1.2138665e-02, -3.6983132e+00, -6.4367266e+00, ...,
           6.8217549e+00,  5.7782011e+00, -5.4132147e+00]],

        [[-5.0323372e+00, -3.3903065e+00, -2.7963824e+00, ...,
           3.9016938e+00,  1.4906535e+00, -2.1907964e+00],
         [-7.7795396e+00, -5.7441168e+00,  3.4615259e+00, ...,
           1.4764800e+00, -2.9045539e+00, -4.4136987e+00],
         [-7.2599754e+00, -3.4636111e+00,  4.3936129e+00, ...,
           1.9856967e+00, -1.0856767e+00, -5.7980385e+00],
         ...,
         [-6.1726952e+00, -3.9608026e+00,  5.5742388e+00, ...,
           4.9396091e+00, -2.8744078e+00, -8.3122082e+00],
         [-1.3442982e+00, -5.5807371e+00,  4.7524319e+00, ...,
           5.0170369e+00,  2.9530718e+00, -7.1846304e+00],
         [-1.7616816e+00, -6.7234058e+00, -8.3512306e+00, ...,
           4.1365266e+00, -2.8818092e+00, -2.9208889e+00]]]],
      dtype=float32)
```

while

```
m_m.predict(data)
```

output

```
array([[[[ -7.836284  ,  -2.3029385 ,  -3.6463926 , ...,  -1.104739  ,
           12.992413  ,  -6.7326055 ],
         [-11.714638  ,  -2.161682  ,  -2.0715065 , ...,  -0.0467519 ,
            6.557784  ,  -2.7576606 ],
         [ -8.029486  ,  -4.068902  ,  -4.6803293 , ...,   7.022674  ,
            7.741771  ,  -1.874607  ],
         ...,
         [-11.229774  ,  -5.3050747 ,   2.807798  , ...,   1.1340691 ,
            4.3236184 ,  -5.2162905 ],
         [-11.458603  ,  -6.2387724 ,   0.25091058, ...,   1.0305461 ,
            5.9631624 ,  -6.284294  ],
         [ -8.663513  ,  -1.8256164 ,  -3.0079443 , ...,   5.9437366 ,
            7.0928698 ,  -1.0781381 ]],

        [[ -4.362539  ,  -2.8450599 ,  -3.1030283 , ...,  -1.5129573 ,
            2.2504683 ,  -8.414198  ],
         [ -6.308961  ,  -4.99597   ,  -3.8596241 , ...,   4.2793174 ,
            2.7787375 ,  -5.9963284 ],
         [ -4.8252788 ,  -1.5710263 ,  -6.083002  , ...,   4.856139  ,
            2.9387665 ,   0.29977918],
         ...,
         [ -0.8481703 ,   5.348722  ,   2.3885899 , ..., -19.35567   ,
           13.1428795 ,  12.364189  ],
         [ -1.8864173 ,  -3.7014763 ,  -2.5292692 , ...,  -3.6618025 ,
            4.3906307 ,   0.03934002],
         [ -6.0526505 ,  -5.504422  ,  -3.8778243 , ...,   4.3741727 ,
            1.0135782 ,  -5.1025114 ]],

        [[ -6.7328253 ,  -1.5671132 ,   0.16782492, ...,  -2.5069456 ,
            1.4343324 ,  -8.59162   ],
         [ -7.5468965 ,  -5.6893063 ,   0.13871288, ...,   0.22174302,
            1.1608338 ,  -8.77916   ],
         [ -5.940791  ,   1.1769392 ,  -4.5080614 , ...,   3.5371704 ,
            2.4181929 ,  -2.7893126 ],
         ...,
         [ -9.490874  ,  -2.3575358 ,   2.5908213 , ..., -18.813345  ,
           -3.4546187 ,   4.8375816 ],
         [ -5.1123285 ,   3.3766522 , -10.71935   , ...,  -5.8476105 ,
           -3.5569503 ,   0.6331433 ],
         [ -6.2075157 ,   0.4942119 ,  -7.044799  , ...,   5.191918  ,
            2.7723277 ,  -4.5243273 ]],

        ...,

        [[ -7.06453   ,  -1.3950944 ,  -0.37429178, ...,  -0.11883163,
            0.22527158,  -9.231563  ],
         [ -4.0204725 ,  -3.6592636 ,   0.15709507, ...,   1.7647433 ,
            4.6479545 ,  -3.8798246 ],
         [  0.75817275,   9.890637  ,  -7.069035  , ...,   2.995041  ,
            6.8453026 ,   6.028713  ],
         ...,
         [ -1.5892754 ,   2.119719  , -10.078391  , ...,  -2.546938  ,
            6.5255003 ,  -6.749384  ],
         [ -3.2769198 ,  -0.46709523,  -2.1529863 , ...,   1.8028917 ,
            7.2509494 ,  -7.5441256 ],
         [ -1.2531447 ,   0.96327865,  -1.0863694 , ...,   2.423694  ,
           -1.1047542 ,  -6.4944725 ]],

        [[-10.218704  ,  -2.5448627 ,  -0.6002845 , ...,   0.80485874,
            2.7691112 ,  -7.374723  ],
         [ -8.354421  ,  -5.461962  ,   5.2284613 , ...,   0.5315646 ,
            5.701563  ,  -4.0477304 ],
         [ -2.7866952 ,  -5.8492465 ,  -1.5627437 , ...,   1.9490132 ,
            4.0491743 ,  -2.7550128 ],
         ...,
         [ -4.5389686 ,  -3.2624135 ,   0.7429285 , ...,   2.5953412 ,
            3.8780956 ,  -8.652936  ],
         [ -5.704813  ,  -3.730238  ,   4.87866   , ...,   2.6826556 ,
            4.8833456 ,  -6.8225956 ],
         [ -0.16680491,  -0.4325713 ,  -4.7689047 , ...,   8.588567  ,
            6.786765  ,  -4.7118473 ]],

        [[ -1.4958351 ,   2.151188  ,  -4.1733856 , ...,  -1.891511  ,
           12.969635  ,  -2.5913832 ],
         [ -7.6865544 ,   0.5423928 ,   6.2699823 , ...,  -2.4558625 ,
            6.1929445 ,  -2.7875526 ],
         [ -6.995783  ,   2.609788  ,   5.6196365 , ...,  -0.6639404 ,
            5.7171726 ,  -3.7962272 ],
         ...,
         [ -3.6628227 ,  -1.3322173 ,   4.7582774 , ...,   2.122392  ,
            3.1294663 ,  -8.338194  ],
         [ -3.0116327 ,  -1.322252  ,   4.802135  , ...,   1.9731755 ,
            8.750839  ,  -6.989321  ],
         [  2.3386476 ,  -2.4584374 ,  -5.9336634 , ...,   0.48920852,
            3.540884  ,  -2.9136944 ]]]], dtype=float32)
```

It obviously not because of floating rounding, since the outputs are quite different. I don't understand why. Please help

Comment: Perhaps the weights are not built, Can you do the same check of weights after the call of the predict method?

Comment: @TouYou Thanks for the comments. I have checked the weights after the predict method and these two models are the same. In fact, these two models are loaded from trained model so I believe the weights should be built already.

Comment: these two models are a copy of each other? Do they use the same activation functions?

Comment: yes they are copy of each other. I just found out the reason. There are BN layers, and although I set them as not trainable, BN layers' weight changed.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the reason by extracting layer by layer. There are BatchNormalizing layers in the model and weight changed although I set them as not trainable.